# How to run a DataTrigger based on if Validation.HasError = False?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatrigger

On my `DataGridTextColumn` I would like to run a `DataTrigger` but only when `Validation.HasError` is `False`

This is what I have at the moment:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Volts" 
                Binding="{Binding DcVolts, Converter={StaticResource StringToDecimalConverter}}" 
                Width="Auto">
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" 
           BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridTextColumnElementErrorStyle}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Validation.HasError}" 
                               Value="False" />
                    <Condition Value="False">
                        <Condition.Binding>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EqualityConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="DcVolts" />
                                <Binding Path="DcSpecVolts" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Condition.Binding>
                    </Condition>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

The thinking behind is that `Validation.HasError` has to be `False` for the `MultiDataTrigger` to set the `BackGround` to `Orange` if the result of the `EqualityConverter` is `False`

This is because if `Validation.HasError` is `True` then I want the usual `Pink` background that my `DataGridTextColumnElementErrorStyle` provides when a rule I have set on the `Property` fails.

I actually got closer with this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Volts" 
                Binding="{Binding DcVolts, Converter={StaticResource StringToDecimalConverter}}" 
                Width="Auto">
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridTextColumnElementErrorStyle}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="False">
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EqualityConverter}" >
                        <Binding Path="DcVolts" />
                        <Binding Path="DcSpecVolts" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

But the problem was that on `Validation.HasError` the messages provided (by the rules I have created) in the `ToolTip` where duplicated.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add parentheses around the binding path since `Validation.HasError` is an attached property:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" 
           Value="True" />
```

Comment: Ah, nice one! That's at least got the triggers working as I want them, now its just the case of the error meesages being duplicated. I have a rule on DcVolts that it cannot be null, so when it is null the cell goes pink and a tooltip provides the message 'Volts cannot be null' but for some reason when I have this trigger on it duplicates the message.

Comment: @Pete: Please ask a new question if you have another issue and please make sure to include a [repo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I did include this issue in my initial question, where I had managed to do what I wanted with the second peice of code but the messages where duplicating. I can create another question but it would basically be the same content. In hindsight maybe I should of included 'Without duplicating validation error messages' in the title. My bad.

Comment: @Pete: Edit your question to include a minimal repo of your issue then.

Comment: I was just in the process of doing so but I would imagine I need to post all the code that's got me to where I am now, my NotifyDataErrorInfo<> Class the Models and Rules etc. thinking I may just acceept your answer as it did solve my initial problem and battle with the rest my self. I can't expect anyone to really spend that much time trying to solve it.